# Remove specific element from json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

i declarate a JSON like this

```
var json{
section1: [],
section2: [],
section3: []
}
```

i want to remove a specific item of this way or something like

```
json[section][index].remove();
```

i tried with this way

```
 delete json[section][index];
```

but when i do this the array elements don't rearrange

Comment: You can use `splice()` to remove an item from an array. --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: If you just want to delete a specific property based on a number called `index`, you could do `delete json["section"+index]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`slice()` is your friend.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

```
json[section] = json[section].slice(index,index+1);
```

Comment: Slice will return a shallow copy (in this case of a single element of the array). You won't change the original array, you won't return any kind of changed array. Did you mix up slice with splice?

Comment: Admittedly it was unclear in the question if the array that they were manipulating was more than a simple array. @assoron, your answer is better anyway.  I will leave this one here for completeness I guess.

Comment: I use the slice to remove the element. i did something like this:

json[place].splice(position, 1);

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Arrays don't have an `remove` function. Use `splice` instead:

```js
var data = {section1: [1,2,3,4]};

const remove = (arr, key, index) => arr[key].splice(index,1)

remove(data,"section1",2)

console.log(data)
```

Keep in mind that this actually changes the original array.